# ISO-8859-1 response encoding

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I want to parse this webpage which contains symbols and Cyrillic letters. GET request return response with wrong encoding, which can not show these letters. What you recommend to prevent this response

```
import requests


url = "http://www.cawater-info.net/karadarya/1991/veg1991.htm"
response = requests.get(url)
print(response.encoding)
print(response.text[:100])
```

I tried to encode this text, but it did not help

```
print(response.text.encode('utf-8')[:100])

print(response.text.encode('cp852')[:100])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the response contains some *cyrillic* alphabet, you need [*cp1251*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251) to decode the content :

```
print(response.content.decode("cp1251")[:100]) # or windows-1251
#<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Оперативные данные по водозаборам бассейна реки Карадарья на период вегетации 199
```